# How to pass values from one page to another page in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, tabs

I have a registration page that contains many input fields. This registration page will open when I click on a **Hyperlink** i.e. registration link, it will open a new tab and then I need to put the values for the respective input fields such as **Email Address**, **First Name**, **Last Name** and so forth through the script (`selenium webdriver - java`).

As of now, it opens a new window with the registration page but its not placing the values in the respective fields..

I have used the following script :

```
webDriver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("paul@vendormate.vm");
webDriver.findElement(By.id("vmBtnSubmitExpReg")).click();      webDriver.findElement(By.name("confirmEmail")).sendKeys("paul@vendormate.vm");
```

Can anyone tell me what shall I do to place the values in the registration page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change window for webdriver

```
 String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); //saves current window name
 //opens new window
 String popupWindow = webDriverExtensions.popupHandle(currentWindow); //now you have second window name
 driver.switchTo().window(popupWindow); // switched to registration window
 // doing your job
 driver.close(); //closing windows
 driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow); //return back to main window

 public String popupHandle(String existingWindowHandle) {
        String popupHandle = null;
        Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String handle : windowHandles) {
            if (!handle.equals(existingWindowHandle)) {
                popupHandle = handle;
                break;
            }
        }
        return popupHandle;
    }
```